# form's submit function does not execute

Tags: forms, blocks

My problem is that when i click the form submit the page reloads but do nothing.
whithin the submit function i have a statement where i dump the $form variable. as nothing happens i figured that the process does not reach the submit function at all and it must be stopping at the validation phase.

below you find my form structure (LoginForm).

### LoginForm.php

```
class LoginForm extends FormBase{
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function getFormId(){
    return 'login_form';
}

/*
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */

public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    //$theme_dir = $GLOBALS["base_url"].'/'.drupal_get_path('theme', 'epw');
    $form = array();

    //$form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'login';

    $form['user_email'] = array(
        '#type' => 'email',
        //'#title' => $this->t('E-mail'),
        '#prefix' => '<div  class="db f5 dark-gray text textinp">E-mail</div >',
        '#default_value' => '',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'mail',
            'name' => 'mail',
            'class' => array('b', 'pa3', 'input-reset', 'ba', 'bg-transparent', 'hover-bg-moon-gray', 'hover-black', 'w-100'),
        ),
    );

    $form['user_pass'] = array(
        '#type' => 'password',
        //'#title' => $this->t('Mot de passe :'),
        '#prefix' => '<div  class="db f5 dark-gray text textinp textinp2">Mot de passe :</div >',
        '#size' => 8,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#attributes' => array(
            'id' => 'password',
            'name' => 'password',
            'class' => array('b', 'pa3', 'input-reset', 'ba', 'bg-transparent', 'hover-bg-moon-gray', 'hover-black', 'w-100'),
        ),
    );

    $form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('SE CONNECTER'),
        '#button_type' => 'primary',
        '#prefix' => '<div class="tr mpoub">
                        <a href="index_mpoublier.php" class="tr f6 dark-gray ">Mot de passe oublié ? </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="subhold tc">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'name' => 'checklogin',
            'class' => array('f6', 'ttu', 'link', 'dim', 'ba', 'ph3', 'pv3', 'dib', 'white', 'bg-green', 'btn'),
        ),
    );

    return $form;
}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public  function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){
    $email_value = $form_state->getValue('user_email');
    $msg = 'Votre email a bien etè envoyè. Vous avez recu une confirmation à ' . $email_value;
    drupal_set_message($msg);
}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $formState){}
}
```

Any ideas on the source of the problem? Am i missing something?

Comment: It's not possible to guess what might be wrong with unseen code. Please produce an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit it into the question, so people have a chance of understanding the source of the problem. Once that's done please flag for re-opening. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i did found the culprit; and it was the attribute "name". it seems that it ovverides the actual name so when i call $form_state->getValue('user_email'); it does not know what i'm talking about but even with $form_state->getValue('mail'); it does not work (don't know why at the moment). and because i made both field required the validation does not success and therefore it does not reach the submit function. so i just remove the attribute name :D